# How to style :root based on Custom Element Attribute

Tags: css, html, web-component, styling, custom-element

#### Update: See: [How to style :root without !important using proper specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162732/how-to-style-root-without-important-using-proper-specificity)

Is it not possible?

This Style rule is totally ignored

[image]

Comment: Some people say screenshot is not the best thing to share the code...

Comment: It shows all the vitals (especially #shadow-root) in one view. Custom Element is created with code from all over different files. Posting parts is like dumping 7 puzzle pieces for people to figure out

Comment: Please read [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) for an explanation of why such screenshots are not liked. 7 puzzle pieces is not good either, which is why we ask for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis to [`:host()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()):

```js
elem.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    .innerHTML = `
    <style>
      :host([player="X"]) { 
        display: inline-block;
        background: red;
        padding 1em; 
      }
    </style>
    Hello World`
```

```html
<game-toes id=elem player="X"></game-toes>
```

Comment: +1 That was indeed the problem at hand; but as updated in my question, not the issue I should have posted