# How to style :root without !important using proper specificity

Tags: css, web-component, custom-element, css-specificity

Inside a **Custom Element** because `border-color` is set on the parent page, I can not make `border-color` work without resorting to `!important`

```
  :host([player="O"]) {
      color: var(--color2);
      border-color: var(--color2) !important;
  }
```

The selector works fine, the color is set,
so it is a Specificity issue

Question: Is it possible without `!important` ?

#### Working snipppet:

```js
window.customElements.define('game-toes', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'Toes';
    shadowRoot.appendChild(document.querySelector('#Styles').content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --boardsize: 40vh;
  --color1: green;
  --color2: red;
}

game-toes {
  width: var(--boardsize);
  height: var(--boardsize);
  border: 10px solid grey;
  background: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<TEMPLATE id="Styles">
  <STYLE>
      :host {
          display: inline-block;
          font-size:2em;
      }

      :host([player="X"]) {
         color: var(--color1);
         border-color: var(--color1);
      }

      :host([player="O"]) {
        color: var(--color2);
        border-color: var(--color2) !important;
      }
  </STYLE>
</TEMPLATE>
<game-toes player="X"></game-toes>
<game-toes player="O"></game-toes>
```

---

[qomponents](http://qomponents.nl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using CSS variable so you can still rely on them like this:

```js
window.customElements.define('game-toes', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'Toes';
    shadowRoot.appendChild(document.querySelector('#Styles').content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --boardsize: 40vh;
  --color1: green;
  --color2: red;
}

game-toes {
  width: var(--boardsize);
  height: var(--boardsize);
  border: 10px solid var(--playercolor,grey);
  color:var(--playercolor,#000);
  background: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<TEMPLATE id="Styles">
  <STYLE>
      :host {
          display: inline-block;
          font-size:2em;
      }

      :host([player="X"]) {
          --playercolor: var(--color1);
      }

      :host([player="O"]) {
          --playercolor: var(--color2);
      }
  </STYLE>
</TEMPLATE>
<game-toes player="X"></game-toes>
<game-toes player="O"></game-toes>
<game-toes ></game-toes>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!... I did the CSS variables for this small snippet only, in my original code I was (of course) struggling with hardcoded color values.

Comment: For reference, could you change ``--c`` to ``--playercolor``, your answer is so much clearer than Bidelman or MDN

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @Temani excellent answer: it happened because the element CSS style for `<games-toes>` will supersede the shadow root `:host` style.

According to [Google's presentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#stylefromoutside):

> Outside styles always win over styles defined in shadow DOM. For example, if the user writes the selector fancy-tabs { width: 500px; }, it will trump the component's rule: :host { width: 650px;}

Comment: Or in programmers terms; the parent always has a higher **_Specificity_**